# Qt : Where is the event type defined?

Tags: windows, qt, message

I'm trying to implement a nativeEventFilter to intercept windows messages in my Qt application according to the explanations provided on the official website :

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html#details

However, they don't mention where/how the `eventType` should be defined, nor the samples provided show any hints. Therefore, `windows_dispatcher_MSG` is obviously undefined in my program.

Comment: Create a byte-array `static const QByteArray windowsDispatcherMSG("windows_dispatcher_MSG");` and compare it with the one you get `eventType == windowsDispatcherMSG`. Furthermore, since `QByteArray` can be casted implicitly from `"windows_dispatcher_MSG"`, you should also be able to directly compare `eventType == "windows_dispatcher_MSG"` where `eventType` is the first parameter of the `nativeEventFilter` function

Comment: I'm confused however with the static_cast as windowsDispatcherMSG is not a type (hence I can not cast from void* to windowsDispatcherMSG* as is done in the Qt sample). There is cleary something I'm missing. Could you please provide a sample snippet to, intercept,say, a WM_DEVICECHANGE message. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a small example:

```
bool Foo::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    static const QByteArray windowsDispatcherMSG("windows_dispatcher_MSG");
    if (eventType != windowsDispatcherMSG)
        return false;

    const MSG * m = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if (m->message != WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        return false;

    /** ...do something... **/
}
```

1. compare the eventType with the one you want to handle
2. cast the void-pointer to `MSG`
3. check the type of the message
4. do whatever you need to do with it